# Reusing h2o model mojo or pojo file from python

Tags: h2o

As H2o models are only reusable with the same major version of h2o they were saved with, an alternative is to save the model as MOJO/POJO format. Is there a way these saved models can be reused/loaded from python code. Or is there any way to keep the model for further development when upgrading the H2O version??

Comment: One approach is to use pyjnius:  https://pypi.org/project/pyjnius/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your model for scoring via python, you could use either [h2o.mojo_predict_pandas](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/h2o.html?#h2o.mojo_predict_pandas) or [h2o.mojo_predict_csv](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/h2o.html?#h2o.mojo_predict_csv). But otherwise if you want to load a binary model that you previously saved, you will need to have compatible versions.

Outside of H2O-3 you can look into pyjnius as Tom recommended: https://github.com/kivy/pyjnius

Comment: Is there any function like load_model() to get the model from zip file? Thanks.

Comment: if you want to use a saved binary model you can use http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-r/docs/reference/h2o.loadModel.html.

Comment: Yes, but this model was exported as mojo in past.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use pysparkling, if you only need it for scoring:

```
from pysparkling.ml import H2OMOJOModel

# Load test data to predict
df = spark.read.parquet(test_data_path)

# Load mojo model
mojo = H2OMOJOModel.createFromMojo(mojo_path)

# Make predictions
predictions = mojo.transform(df)

# Show predictions with ground truth (y_true and y_pred)
predictions.select('your_target_column', 'prediction').show()
```